# Apache NIFI Faild to bind to xxx

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I try to start my nifi server with toolkit, when I set the "nifi.properties" https-host be 127.0.0.1 my server can start, and I use "jps" can see the nifi is on running, meanwhile the log file shows nifi is running, but I can't through my cloud server ip+port to visited nifi.

When I change the config of "https-host" to be my public IP adress, the log shows faild to bind the IP. Did somebody have same problem with me.

[error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGk62.png)

Comment: When I set https-host be 127.0.0.1 then nifi can success started, but I try to visit in the brower through my public IP adress and I can't connect it.

Comment: What if you set the value to 0.0.0.0 instead of the IP and then browsed to the public IP after rebooting NiFi?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that to make the NiFi instance available through the Public IP, change the property of 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 and then restart NiFi. After restarting NiFi, try browsing to the public IP address.
Another option is to replace the 127.0.0.1 with the public IP address of the host and then restart NiFi. After restarting NiFi, try browsing to the public IP address.

Comment: I try to set the host be 0.0.0.0, but result is same. The nifi  serve is successful started, but when I use brower it just show refused my connection.

Comment: I restart serve now it worked, but the when I visited web get below error info: The request contained an invalid host header [xxxxx(my ip)] in the request [/nifi]. Check for request manipulation or third-party intercept.

Comment: By the way, my nifi version is 1.14.

Comment: What you should do is mark this as successful and then start another question??

Comment: I change the nifi config proxy and whitelist, and now it worked, thanks for you ansear.

Comment: I was facing the same issue but adding the Public Id+port and whitelisting the Public Ip  resolved it.